# Конфликты при слиянии веток

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Хочу слить *мастер-ветку*, т.к. там были изменения, в мою *ветку А*.

Делаю следующее из ветки *А*:

```
$ git merge --no-ff master
```

Получаю следующие сообщения:

```
Auto-merging app/views/posts/_poll_fields.html.haml
Auto-merging app/views/posts/_form.html.haml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/views/posts/_form.html.haml
Removing app/views/polls/show.html.haml
CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.haml deleted
  in master and modified in HEAD.
  Version HEAD of app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.haml left in tree.
Removing app/views/polls/_poll_items.html.haml
CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/views/polls/_poll_item.html.haml deleted
  in master and modified in HEAD.
  Version HEAD of app/views/polls/_poll_item.html.haml left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml deleted
  in master and modified in HEAD.
  Version HEAD of app/views/polls/_poll_fields.html.haml left in tree.
Removing app/views/polls/_items.html.haml
Removing app/views/polls/_form_item.html.haml
Auto-merging app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Как я вижу из логов, редактировались одинаковые файлы в ветках. Как правильно исправить данные ошибки? Необходимо изменения из *мастер-ветки* слить в *ветку А*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас возникло два вида конфликтов:

1. *CONFLICT (content)* — в файл внесены изменения в обеих ветках и эти изменения конфликтуют друг с другом.

   место конфликта (их может быть больше одного) будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   <<<<<<< HEAD
   изменения, внесённые в вашу ветку
   =======
   изменения, внесённые в ветку master
   >>>>>>> master
   ```

   приведите файл к тому виду, какой вам требуется, не забыв при этом удалить вставленные *git*-ом «служебные» строки, начинающиеся с символов `<`, `=`, `>`.

   добавьте файл в *индекс*:

   ```
   $ git add путь/к/файлу
   ```
2. *CONFLICT (modify/delete)* — файл удалён в одной из веток и модифицирован в другой.

   варианты решения (выбор диктует ваша задача):

   1. удалить файл в вашей ветке:

      ```
      $ git rm путь/к/файлу
      ```
   2. сохранить файл в вашей ветке:

      ```
      $ git add путь/к/файлу
      ```

**после** разрешения **всех** конфликтов (сверяйтесь по выводу `git status`) сделайте `git commit`.